# cordova run ios --device not launching app to device

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, command-line-interface

I have configured for Cordova 5.0 and started using for iOS application. Successfully creating and running app on simulator. For device i am using Xcode to launch app.
`ios-deploy -c:` result

```
[....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[....] Found iPad 2 'Ipad' (DeviceID) connected through USB.
[....] Found (null) connected through USB.
```

While launching with device using command

```
cordova run ios --device
```

Successfully build application and shows the

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

[....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[....] Found iPad 2 'IPad' (deivceId) connected through USB.
run
```

And it is not installing app on device.
I also tried `cordova run ios --target="Ipad"` `cordova run ios --device --target="Ipad"`  also not working

Also for ios-deploy my iphone is not visible returns `Found (null) connected through USB.`
Ipad version: 7.x, iphone version: 8.x, ios-deploy version: 1.6.0

Comment: Is your Xcode showing device connected? or Have you selected device to launch app? Also read doc for launching app on device: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html -- It  has pretty good explanation

Comment: I am able to launch app in device from Xcode

Comment: This is what I found in Cordova docs - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in your Terminal (over your cordova app folder):

Find and replace: YOUR_APP_NAME_BUNDLE, to your app name, over this path:

```
ios-deploy --bundle "platforms/ios/build/device/YOUR_APP_NAME_BUNDLE.ipa"
```